# Frustrated with my inability to find a good library, framework, or engine- Any suggestions besides SDL?

Tags: frameworks, 2d, libraries

For the last few years I have been developing a 2D video game, which would most likely fall under the category of a singleplayer RPG with a post-release goal of adding in multiplayer. My goals have always been very realistic, attempting to achieve small chunks of progress before anything too serious.

My 2D game requires a hefty sum of assets (artwork; primarily images, some which are very large). While most of the last few years has been working on the artwork, for the last year I have been sharpening my programming skills, learning about game engineering, and building small games in various languages and frameworks/engines. After much work with different frameworks/engines, I realized I need (or at least want) to squeeze every last bit of performance that I can. My game will most likely take 1-2GB of ram maximum, with at least 4-6GB of HDD space. With content expansions I'd expect it to get quite large, at least on the HDD. This is why I, very unfortunately, do not believe HTML5 is ready for my game. Otherwise I would choose it, buy specific (highly rated) books, and start work right away.

I started my project with XNA Game Studio for primarily two reasons: a hefty bulk of tutorials at XNA GPA Tutorials to give me an easier start, and the ability to port to a secondary platform besides my primary target of Windows (port to XBOX). Soon after some development, I ran into a few issues with the framework, content pipeline and its (crappy) compression into XNA's (crappy) .xnb format, and the understanding of severe limitations for XBOX Live Arcade games and their size limit. The XNA GPA tutorials are nice, but I realized they're nothing special that I need to build my game using another framework.

SDL had amazing performance, so I started to work on developing my game. Progress was quite nice, and I did not run into any problems. However, with the way SDL is advertised (talked about) I assumed it used OPEN GL by default, not software rendering. I implemented some OPENGL, but read online that its open GL implementation was a bit rough, and that SFML is a much better engine for those who do not mind that it is higher level.

Off to SFML I went! And after a few days, it went straight into the trash. Reading about intel graphic problems with rendering, having to trash 1.6 due to the unfixable ATI glitch, and then trolling through google to find a custom nightly build of 2.0 that works with mingw 4.7.1, and learning that I am not the only person skeptical of SFML's quality as a whole, as well as some irrational changes in intuitive code from 1.6 to 2.0, I just wanted to give up in frustration.

So I am back to SDL, with very little developed. It is not that I want to use SDL, but that I cannot find a framework that is suitable for my game that is better than SDL. I fell in love with HTML5 and then was very interested in Isogenic Engine (HTML5) but I severely doubt that HTML5 is capable of handling my large (and numerous) sprite sheets and heavy asset 2D game.

Portability is important to me, but not a requirement. I figure I might as well just start programming my game for just Windows, and then once it is finished if I want to, then port it elsewhere. The best piece of advice I've ever received was, "It doesn't matter what you use. Just start, and do it. Having a completed game is more important than having a high performance piece of incomplete software."

However, I have heard by many that it would resolve a lot of headaches and some extra heavy lifting if I were to pick a library/framework/engine that handled networking at a higher level than what I'd have to implement if I were to use SDL.

I've researched game engines for years now, so I am really looking for convincing reasons to pick [your suggestions] as opposed to a simple, "I haven't used it, but..."

I want to be convinced away from SDL and onto something higher level, but I am having trouble finding reasons to choose differently. There are hundreds of game engines on wikipedia's list, and many more not listed-- but sorting through the chaff is exhausting, especially when I have already tried so many and been quite disappointed with the results.

Think of my game as a high resolution image version of Baldurs Gate 2, Sanitarium, Diablo 2, or Ultima Online. Not in gameplay, but in the fact it is entirely in 2D images which result in art style, chunks of ram usage, tons of HDD space, and a few quite large spritesheets/image sequences (Dragons, for example) amongst many very small sprite sheets (7MB total HDD space for a human character in 15 animations across 8 directions, and under 30MB memory usage for the sheets).

Also, thank you for letting me vent while I ask for detailed suggestions.

Comment: I would love to be proven wrong that HTML5 cannot handle my intense graphic requirements and large spritesheets.

Here is an example of the game so far (very little work is done, as I only just now completed parsing XML files from TexturePacker and translating that information into actual animated sprites)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqkoc6ueiz72nnx/!Test11212312.png

Although I can readily shrink the size of large characters (Dragons, Giants, etc.) it is not my intention to do so. I can, however, not use spritesheets for large entities to prevent 8196x8196 size textures being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same problem as you. I would really want to find right framework. I tried a lot and i think i found it. It's Polycode http://polycode.org/  http://polycode.tumblr.com/

But it's not finished(IDE, library is usable) and developer says it's going to be till the end of January. But i started developing my own just in case Polycode disappoint me.

Comment: Thank you, and I hope everything goes the best way for you!